# Canary Islands, Tenerife unlimited data SIM

Tags: budget, internet, canary-islands

I am going on holiday to Tenerife (Canary Islands), I already have two MiFi dongles and only need a SIM.

**What are cheapest unlimited (or large) data deals in Tenerife for a week?**

Comment: What do you mean by `best`? Cheap? More coverage? SIM card colour? You should probably narrow this down to make it answerable.

Comment: @JoErNanO Hi thanks for advice, cheapest, and prefered color red :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I have found so far is Foto Royale in Centro Commercial Fanabe. 2 x 1.5 GB Vodaphone sims for 30 euros valid for 30 days after first use. Overall expiry date October 2016 even if not used.